# regex 8 digits, last alpha numeric

Tags: regex

I need a regex 
where the value should be 8 characeters long,
it should start with an 8, and the last digit can be alphanumeric.

eg: 
these should work:

8765432A

87654321

Im struggling with the last character:

```
^[ ]*(8)[0-9]{6}[ ]*$
```

can you help?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need a character class (`[ ]`) for a single character (space); but perhaps you want `[[:space:]]*` (assuming POSIX re's)?

Comment: However matching `[[:space:]]*` can make input variable length not just `8 characters long`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
 ^8[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

OR with word boundaries:

```
 \b8[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z0-9]\b
```

Comment: That won't allow an alphabetic "last digit".

Comment: Yes just realized and fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression `8[0-9]{6}[0-9a-zA-Z]`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
^8\d{6}[A-Za-z0-9]$
```

should work. Basically it's 8, 6 digits and one alphanumeric character. No characters before or after the matching string.

Comment: `\w` includes underscore as well.